# Uploading an image to my database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I know it's wrong to upload images into a db but I need to do it for now.

My function looks like this:

```
public function runk_image_post()
{
    $id = $this->get('id');
    $imagePath = $_FILES['data']['tmp_name'];

    /// $imagePath = Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/php6cpBhM

    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->query("UPDATE runks SET runk_image = LOAD_FILE('$imagePath') WHERE runk_id='$id';");
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM runks WHERE runk_id = '$id';");
    $message = $query->row();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $data = ['message' => 'Image not uploaded'];
        $this->response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        $this->response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

It returns the HTTP_OK response but nothing gets added in the runk_image column (type: blob) in my database. What am I doing wrong?

I think it has to do with my $imagePath variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you use LOAD_FILE(), you should pass the absolute path of the file.

> EDIT: I do not think LOAD_FILE() should be used (or at least its no good practice) because using it asserts that your web server and the database server have access to the same file system, which is not always the case.

Otherwize you should load the file contents to a variable and pass it as value to your 'runk_image' blob, in this case the code should look as follows:

```
public function runk_image_post(){
    $id = $this->get('id');
    $imagePath = $_FILES['data']['tmp_name'];

    $imageBin = file_get_contents($imagePath);

    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->where('runk_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('runks',array('runk_image'=>$imageBin));
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    $message = $query->row();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $data = ['message' => 'Image not uploaded'];
        $this->response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        $this->response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }}
```

Comment: this will give me an error: 

            <p>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Y' at line 1</p>
            <p>UPDATE runks SET runk_image = '�PNG

Comment: Ah! of course you should run the proper escaping, i will modify the answer accordingly but here's a detailed read :(https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/inserting-and-then-retrieving-a-blob-data-from-mysql-database-using-php/98266 @RutgerHuijsmans

Comment: this will result in the following error: 

  <p>Error Number: 1064</p>
            <p>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?PNG\r\n\Z\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\\r?f\0\0\0gAMA\0\0???a\0\0\0 c' at line 1</p>
            <p>UPDATE runks SET runk_image = ''�PNG\r\n\Z\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\\r�f\0\0\0gAMA\0\0���a\0\0\0 cHRM\0\0z&\0\0��\0\0�\0\0\0��\0\0u0\0\0�`\0\0:�\0\0p��Q<\0\0\0 pHYs\0\0\0\0\0��\0\0YiTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp\0\0\0\0\0

Comment: Did you try to use CIs query builders, like `$this->db->where('runk_id', $id); $this->db->update('runks',array('runk_image'=>$imageBin));` ?